# Up button on toolbar present but not working MVC architecture app tricky implementation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, model-view-controller

I have implemented fragments in this stackoverflowAPI app and after refactoring from using to activity I've used fragments. But I,ve losed the functionality I had for going from the up buutton on the toolbar back to the initail fragment which is a list.

I had implemented this in an activity previously and  got it working.

now I'm clutching at straws because I'm throwing everything at it like onOPtionsItemSelected retrurning false andsetHasOptionsMenu to true this obviously wouldnt work and I'm left thinking why cant we just have a kind of method like to get the supportactionbar and set it has up enabled etc...obviously this isn't the case.

Any help, links , elaborations are most appreciated.

---

QuestionsDetailFragment

```
public class QuestionDetailsFragment extends BaseFragment implements QuestionDetailViewMvc.Listener, FetchQuestionDetailsUseCase.Listener, BackPressedListener {

    private static final String ARG_QUESTION_ID = "ARG_QUESTION_ID";

    public static QuestionDetailsFragment newInstance(String questionId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_QUESTION_ID, questionId);
        QuestionDetailsFragment fragment = new QuestionDetailsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private FetchQuestionDetailsUseCase mFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase;
    private BackPressDispatcher mBackPressDispatcher;
    private ScreensNavigator mScreensNavigator;
    private ToastHelper mMessagesDisplayer;
    private QuestionDetailViewMvc mViewMvc;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase = getCompositionRoot().getFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase();
        mMessagesDisplayer = getCompositionRoot().getToastHelper();

        mBackPressDispatcher = getCompositionRoot().getBackPressDispatcher();
        mViewMvc = getCompositionRoot().getViewMvcFactory().getQuestionDetailViewMvc(container);

        mScreensNavigator = getCompositionRoot().getScreensNavigator();
        return mViewMvc.getRootView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase.registerListener(this);
        mViewMvc.registerListener(this);
        mViewMvc.showProgressIndication();
        mBackPressDispatcher.registerListener(this);

        mFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase.fetchQuestionDetailsAndNotify(getQuestionId());


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mFetchQuestionDetailsUseCase.unregisterListener(this);
        mViewMvc.unregisterListener(this);

        mBackPressDispatcher.unnregisterListener(this);

    }

    private void bindQuestionDetails(QuestionDetails questionDetails) {
        mViewMvc.hideProgressIndication();
        mViewMvc.bindQuestion(questionDetails);
    }


    private String getQuestionId() {

        return getArguments().getString(ARG_QUESTION_ID);
    }


    @Override
    public void onQuestionDetailsFetched(QuestionDetails questionDetails) {
        bindQuestionDetails(questionDetails);

    }

    @Override
    public void onQuestionDetailsFailed() {
        mViewMvc.hideProgressIndication();
        mMessagesDisplayer.showUseCaseError();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationUPClicked() {

        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemClicked(DrawerItems item) {
        switch (item) {
            case QUESTIIONS_LIST:
                mScreensNavigator.toQuestionsList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        if (mViewMvc.isDrawerOpen()) {
            mViewMvc.closeDrawer();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

ScreenNavigator.java

```
public class ScreensNavigator {


    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private final FragmentFrameWrapper mFragmentFrameWrapper;

    public ScreensNavigator(FragmentManager mFragmentManager, FragmentFrameWrapper fragmentFrameWrapper) {
        this.mFragmentManager = mFragmentManager;
        this.mFragmentFrameWrapper = fragmentFrameWrapper;
    }


    public void toQuestionDetails(String questionId) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(mFragmentFrameWrapper.getFragmentFrame().getId(), QuestionDetailsFragment.newInstance(questionId)).commit();
    }

    public void toQuestionsList() {
        mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(mFragmentFrameWrapper.getFragmentFrame().getId(), QuestionsListtFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    }

    public void navigateUpToList() {

        // here I would like to some help..........................

    }
}
```

in this class I was initially using a context but after refactoring to fragments it didn't help so I removed it...........

---

BaseFragment

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private ControllerCompositionRoot mControllerCompositionRoot;

    protected ControllerCompositionRoot getCompositionRoot() {

        if(mControllerCompositionRoot == null) {

            mControllerCompositionRoot = new ControllerCompositionRoot(
                    ((CustomApplication) requireActivity().getApplication()).getCompositionRoot(),
                    requireActivity()
            );

        }

        return  mControllerCompositionRoot;
    }
}
```

I'll add the repo aswell here

[github](https://github.com/BenMohammad/architectureMVC)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you are calling `mActivity.onBackPressed();` when you press the up Botton. `onBackPressed` ends the current `Activity` by default. When you implemented the app as multiple activities, `onBackPressed()` killed the last `Activity` but when you implemented it as `Fragments` it now kills more than you want it to.

I tried to run your app and the button in the toolbar seems to take me back to the main page when I press it when testing on an Android 24 emulator. I thought that was what you wanted the app to do initially, so if the first part doesn't help you out, let me know what you want the button to do instead.

Comment: Yeah the issue was getting it back to the last fragment which is does just had to implement this in a ToolBarMvc thanks you were right.

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks for the upvote and check.